# How can I implement video chat in my website using Django?

Tags: django, video, chat

I want to develop a website in which users can have video chat and they can connect to other user anonymously without had been added by the other person as friend. I also want that all the active users list is displayed on the website. So somebody please suggest me how can I implement it on django?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a third party service for this. Or you can use WebRTC. There are some nodejs packages which can help you do this. I like "EasyRTC" for that.

Or if you want to use Python, you can use Twisted. Here's a tutorial (found on Google, not tested by myself - https://ferretfarmer.net/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-1/)

In essence, Django doesn't handle the video streaming/chat part. You can use Django for authentication and serving the required html and other stuff. But the video chat needs to depend on other services.

Comment: You may upvote and accept it as the answer if you think it answers your query. Otherwise we could discuss further.

Comment: could you please give some examples of these services please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a video calling and chat application using django, django_channels, you can refer to this [Github Repository](https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/Video_call_and_chat_in_Django) .
It also tells you how to deploy your app to google app engine flex with Redis instance.

It took me a long time to build this, so I created a detailed basic public repository to help someone like myself and for future reference.