# Best way to implement Video Chat with Django Backend?

Tags: django, video, react-native

So i'm trying to build a React Native with basic video chat functionality.

So far I have a Django backend and users can signin/signup/signout. Other than that, what's the best way to tackle this video chat? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234291/3842788 Working example

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC for building video chat in React Native.

Find more details here
https://webrtchacks.com/reacting-to-react-native-for-native-webrtc-apps-alexey-aylarov/

https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc