# Implementing a video call interface in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hey there im trying to implement a video call interface in my django application but unable to find docs .I found twilio but the support was for javascript and webrtc for nodejs.
Are there any third party libs that  i can integrate in django app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234291/3842788 Working example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party service for this. Or you can use WebRTC. There are some nodejs packages which can help you do this. I like "EasyRTC" for that.

Or if you want to use Python, you can use Twisted. Here's a tutorial (found on Google, not tested by myself - https://ferretfarmer.net/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-1/)

In essence, Django doesn't handle the video streaming/chat part. You can use Django for authentication and serving the required html and other stuff. But the video chat needs to depend on other services

Do like it and accept the answer if you are satisfied Thanks!

Comment: the blog you just shared was just realtime chat.

Comment: and i did check out webrtc as i mentioned above i need something to be integrated via python

Comment: Django doesn't handle the video streaming/chat part. You can use Django for authentication and serving the required html and other stuff. But the video chat needs to depend on other services